I am trying to update ubuntu WSL i.e ubuntu 20.04(app) on windows 10 pro OS, it is showing error 502 connection refused or 500 no space on device
500  No space left on device [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
502  Connection refused [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  502  Connection refused [IP: 185.125.190.82 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  502  Connection refused [IP: 185.125.190.81 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64  502  Connection refused [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  500  No space left on device [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en.gz  500  No space left on device [IP: 185.125.190.83 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to Superuser. Please note that a copy/paste of a log does not really make a question. Also, there are formatting tools in the editor that will help you a lot. Did you check available disk space? That seems a pretty key aspect of this issue, and that information is not included in the question.

It seams that you don't have enough free space on your disk for the download. Ubuntu takes around 6Go for download then around 20Go when installed. How many free space do you have on your computer ?

Welcome to Superuser. This is part question, part possible answer, and as such makes more sense as a comment. I know you don't have the reputation to comment yet, but making good contributions in the form of well presented questions and good, complete answers will help you earn this reputation pretty quickly. Posting comments as answers will not help you earn this rep.
